# How can I automate purchasing a ticket on Eventbrite?

Tags: automation, eventbrite

A particular event on Eventbrite that I would like to attend has been selling out within a few minutes of the ticket sales being opened. How would I automate the purchase of a ticket so that I can be sure of getting one before they are all sold out?

Comment: I think stackoverflow skews towards technical questions instead of something generic like this

Answer (score 1):

It's not really Stackowerflow question.

Try to write Selenium script that will monitor event page and perform user actions to buy ticket. 
Or use [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) to capture and play required steps if you don't have dev skills.